# How to do an SQL update with a multi subrequest inside?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I would like to do that :

```
UPDATE `data` d 
  SET map_lat, map_lon = 
    (SELECT latitude, longitude FROM  `maps_city` c WHERE c.zipcode =  d.zipcode)
```

How can I do it with SQL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
UPDATE  `data` d, `maps_city` c
SET d.map_lat = c.latitude, 
    d.map_lon = c.longitude
WHERE c.zipcode =  d.zipcode
```

Have a look at [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) and look for *Multiple-table syntax*

Comment: OMG it is taking ages ! In `maps_city` there is more than 50000 entries and even more in `data` ...

Answer (score 1):

Mysql support multiple-table update,
syntax like

```
UPDATE
  data, maps_city
SET 
  data.map_lat=maps_city.latitude,
  data.map_lon=maps_city.longitude
WHERE 
  data.zipcode=maps_city.zipcode
```

details : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html